# How to use check boxes to find total cost of computer peripherals?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

In my program, I want to calculate the total price of a computer and 6 other peripheral items. I have 6 check boxes for the 6 peripheral items. I was wondering how you can assign a value to a checkbox and then be able to use that value in your calculation? For example, if I were to select "mouse" and "keyboard", how do I write a code that lets me add together the cost for only the mouse and keyboard respectively and the cost for the computer?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd recommend is to define a `ComputerPeripheral` class that encapsulates a `String description` & `int costInCents` (don't use `double` or other floating point numbers for monetary amounts).

Then you might keep an array of check boxes (e.g. `JCheckBox[] peripheralsToInclude`) & corresponding array of peripherals (e.g. `ComputerPeripheral[] peripherals`). Add an `ActionListener` to the check boxes.

When an action is detected, iterate the array of check boxes and determine if that one is selected. If so, get the corresponding peripheral and add the cost to an `int total`. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Read about ActionListner and add to your program accordingly.